# Print the correct expression and the operator in the final output

Tags: arrays, c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      float value1[3]; 
      float value2[3];
      char operator[3];
      char * opstr;

      float results[3] = {0};
      
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      printf("Type in your expression. \n");
      scanf ("%f %c %f",&value1[i],&operator[i],&value2[i]);
      switch(operator[i]) 
      {
        case '+':
          results[i] = value1[i] + value2[i];
          opstr = "plus";
          break;
        case '-':
          results[i] = value1[i] - value2[i];
          opstr = "minus";
          break;
        case '*':
          results[i] = value1[i] * value2[i];
          opstr = "times";
          break;
        case '/':
          results[i] = value1[i] / value2[i];
          opstr = "divided by";
          break;
        default:
          printf("Unknown Operator \n");
          return 0;
        }
     }
     for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
          printf("Result of %.2f %s %.2f is : %.2f\n", value1[i], opstr, value2[i], results[i]);
     }

}
```

This C program has the user enter 3 expressions and the program will return an answer. The problem is that the output looks something like this:

```
Type in your expression: 3+2

Type in your expression: 3*6

Type in your expression: 1+4

Result of 1 + 4 is: 5

Result of 1 + 4 is: 18

Result of 1 + 4 is: 5
```

Where the result of the expression is correct, but it doesn't print the correct expression at the end. It only prints the more recent expression (1+4).

My question is how do I print the correct expression and the operator in the final result as a string(plus, minus, divided by, etc) to look more like this:

```
Type in your expression: 3+2

Type in your expression: 3*6

Type in your expression: 1+4

Result of 3 plus 2 is: 5

Result of 3 times 6 is: 18

Result of 1 plus 4 is: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is

```
  char * opstr;
  switch(operator[i]){
     case '+':
      opstr = "plus";
      break;
    case '-':
      opstr = "minus";
      break
 ....
  }
```

and `printf` opstr as `%s`

Answer (score 0):

you need 3 arrays

one for the left arguments, one for the operations and one for the right arguments.

```
  float lefts[3], 
  float rights[3];
  char operators[3];
  float results[3] = {0};
  ....
```

then in the loop

```
     scanf ("%f %c %f",&lefts[i],&operators[i],&rights[i]);
```

Comment: ok the expressions are printing correctly but not the operators. I put:                       
          case '-':
          results[i] = value1[i] - value2[i];
          operator[i] = "minus";
          break;                                                                                                                                      then in the final print statement:  printf("Result of %.2f %c %.2f is : %.2f\n", value1[i], operator[i], value2[i], results[i]);

Comment: look at my other answer

Comment: Alright now it only prints the most recent one. So if I put 1+2, 1*3, 1/2, it prints all 3 results as "divided by".

Comment: @Knight_Drive update the question with your latest code, plus please dont just copy, try to understand whats going on

Comment: yeah sorry I've just been tackling this for quite a while and it's getting a little frustrating.

Comment: @Knight_Drive  do the opstr stuff inside the print loop, not while you do tha calculations